# What does "tremor" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Man intrudes into the house and takes woman with her kids hostage. I do not understand the meaning of tremor here. If it's quiver, how can you swallow it? Is it bile? Or sour saliva? Thanks for help.

> “Nice place you got here.” He turns back with an appreciative nod, and
> I swallow down a **sour tremor**. His words are pleasant enough but not
> his tone, so hostile that my nerves stir with fright. I can hear the
> thoughts tripping through his brain. That we have too much. That he
> has too little. It’s such an about-face from his demeanor in the
> garage, calm and matter-of-fact even when waving around his gun, it
> makes my legs go mushy.

Kimberly Belle "My darling husband"

Comment: It's probably more figurative than literal, but the "sourness" is from ***stomach acid***. See [*research suggests that **anxiety** might make **acid reflux** symptoms worse*.](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/acid-reflux-and-anxiety#summary)

Comment: ... lately I often get the feeling nervous new TV presenters and the like are struggling to avoid vomiting from tension, which is reflected in a halting delivery with occasional inappropriate pauses. Which *might* be down to autocue problems, but I'm sure it's often ***butterflies in the stomach***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'tremor' is a feeling of fear or alarm. One can swallow to suppress a feeling (or its expression by the face or body). In this case, the narrator had a 'sour'  feeling of fear.

> Swallow (verb)
>
> to use the muscles of your throat, as if moving something from your
> mouth into your stomach, **because you are nervous or frightened**, or are
> about to say something

[Swallow (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swallow)

We can figuratively say that we 'swallow' (overcome) fear, nervousness, etc, without necessarily physically using the throat.